# Questions about literature

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I read a while ago that the Literature Stack Exchange website was closed and I read also the reasons. Moreover, I would want to know where could I ask questions like these ones, if there is a place:

- What does the writer of X book mean by...?
- What is the message the writer wants to transmit in X poem?

I actually agree that questions with book recommendations should not be accepted, but...

> Is there a place for these type of questions?

Comment: If it's a question about language semantics, [English Language and Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/) would work.

Comment: @RobertHarvey If not?

Comment: But not questions about divining the meaning of an author's work.  I would imagine that such questions are too speculative to make good questions in the SE format; the only site that entertains such questions is Science Fiction and Fantasy.

Comment: Can't imagine what else is relevant to wish to discern than the author's intended meaning. If this is out of bounds then it is purely a literary criticism site. Why rely on some critic's opinion? If members are college grads in arts and letters then they have been trained to think. That should be the only prerequisite for answering a question. Including some type of supportive evidence for your observation is fine. But literature is NOT a science. An informed take on a particular piece should be enough. But please ditch the sci-Fi, that is not literature. Even, Foundation and Empire is not lit